# Connection does not take place when I use createGroup() method in WifiDirect

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I try to create a group by connecting devices to the Group Owner(GO) via WiFiDirect. To do so, among number of devices I picked one of them to be GO. I do this through createGroup() method. Then, I send connection invitation from GO to clients automatically, but it doesn't work. On the GO side it seems like the invited device is stuck at "Invited" status. Moreover, I tried connecting to the GO through sending connection invitation to the GO. Again, on the supposedly-client side, GO seems to be stuck at "Invited" status. All in all, when I use createGroup() method and assign a device to be the GO, I simply cannot make any connection to that device via WiFiDirect. This will sound like a silly question, but I go nuts. What might be the problem here?